Why does my table header take half the table height in Firefox?
I have a table in HTML:


<div style="height: 90vh">
  <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <table style="height: 100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>



When I open it in Firefox the header takes half the table height, but when I open it on Google Chrome the header takes just the height of its content.
Did you know about this issue any thing?
I expect it to work like Google Chrome and the header to take just the height of its content.

The snippet renders exactly the same for me in both Chrome and Firefox (current versions, on MacOs Ventura.)

to confirm the OP issue, the snippet actually renders differently depending on Firefox/Chrome. On Chrome the header's height is the bare minimum while the body takes all the remaning height (styling borders would better help seeing it). And the answer given doesn't strictly respond to why it happens. I suppose it's because of browser's defaults for each given element

Do you use a css reset ? Those are very helpfull to prevent those kind of dumb presets

No, I don't use anything but the styles in the code snippet.

to be fair, before I supposed the reason was the browser's default.. but actually I had no evidence and just speculated. I later dug further and found out it was not the case. The reason could be on how each browser deals with 100% heights internally and probably it's more related with their own implementation of how handling document flow

You can add height: 1em; for th. If there is a line break in a th, it will grow automatically according to the content.


th {
  height: 1em;
}
<div style="height: 90vh">
  <div style="height: 100%">
    <table style="height: 100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Header 1</th>
          <th>Header 2</th>
          <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data 1</td>
          <td>Data 2</td>
          <td>Data 3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>




Why did you put display: table in a table tag ?

i was testing sorry
